# How to override a JavaScript value with greasemonkey?

Tags: greasemonkey

I usually have to visit a website:

```
https://xyz.asd.com/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?sc=4325286581&event=loadapp&value=incident
```

that contains the following line in it's HTML code:

```
SESSION_TIMEOUT = 1800;//in seconds.
```

I need to change this string to ex.:

```
SESSION_TIMEOUT = 1800000;//in seconds.
```

Greasmonkey can do this. But how? I kept googling for hours, but the original line is untouched... Can someone help me?

Comment: Is SESSION_TIMEOUT a global JavaScript variable?

Comment: @cmorse - I think its responsible for the webpage to timeout/log out the logged in user.

Comment: @LanceBaynes - I was thinking that if it is just a JavaScript variable then you could just set it to the desired value with a greasemonkey script.

Comment: @LanceBaynes: You should look for a browser-specific solution to access the original window context, this can differ between browsers. It could be so that the session timeout is somehow forced on you (perhaps by a timer or AJAX calls), in which case you aren't able to change it. Also note that changing a client-side timeout won't impose a server-side timeout change...

Comment: Why don't you change the session time out in Maximo application? If you use LDAP, there is also an LDAP token that expires that is separate from the session time out if you use WebSphere application server.

Answer (score 2):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Script Name Here
// @namespace     http://www.site.com/your-personal-namespace
// @description   An Greasemonkey script that changes the session timeout value
// @include       https://xyz.asd.com
// ==/UserScript==
window.SESSION_TIMEOUT = 1800000;
```

?

Comment: this one doesn't work too :\

Comment: can you provide more details? how have you checked that it doesn't work - have you used, for example, javascript console to check if the variable was changed or not? is there an error message?

Comment: The version with unsafeWindow should work. Mine does not seem to, but cannot comment on that one, so commented here. But please add some more details as to why that one does not work.

Comment: @eis: `window` doesn't give full access, `unsafeWindow`is browser-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `unsafeWindow`, which, as the name infers, is not the most secure method -- but if all you are doing is changing the value of a page based variable, there's no risk involved.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Script Name Here
// @namespace     http://www.site.com/your-personal-namespace
// @description   An Greasemonkey script that changes the session timeout value
// @include       https://xyz.asd.com
// ==/UserScript==

unsafeWindow.SESSION_TIMEOUT = 1800000;
```

If you just use `window.SESSION_TIMEOUT`, you more than likely will not be accessing the correct scope, and your `SESSION_TIMEOUT` variable would go unmodified, and a new one created inside another context / scope.

Comment: it doesn't work, sorry :\

Comment: @lawrencealan: `unsafeWindow` is browser-dependent.

Comment: @TomWijsman Where do you see that `unsafeWindow` is browser dependent? It was my understanding that it is implemented in the GreaseMonkey plugin itself...

Comment: @LanceBaynes try using a timer, I have a feeling that the value is being overwritten due to the order of inclusion, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @lawrencealan: It uses `wrappedJSObject`, which is available in Firefox but not available in Google Chrome and probably also not in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @TomWijsman Greasemonkey is officially only an extension for Mozilla Firefox, other browsers are not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @lawrencealan: Userscripts, if you follow browser-independent practices (which aren't hard to achieve), run in most browsers including Firefox, Google Chrome and Internet Explorer. They indeed officially target Firefox but it's used more widely these days, I'm assuming the OP could use Google Chrome or IE as well as that changing the variable doesn't have effect after page initialization as a timer might be initialized...

Answer (score 0):

Good old

`location.href="javascript:(function(){ window.SESSION_TIMEOUT = 1800000; })()"`

trick should work.

Comment: Can I ask how to implement this? to a userscript??

Comment: I tried it in a userscript. it doesn't work either :D:D maybe the Maximo tool is based on something that overrides this somehow...it's a mistical thing for me...

Comment: @LanceBaynes: Although my code should work, [here is a Q&A explaining this trick and another trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5006952/47064). I've used the script trick before as well as well as that location trick and the one I mentioned. If none of these work, you simply can't do anything with that value. It might even be so that that value is solely used to start a timer and later not used anymore in any way...